# AngularJS replace using regex on template

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, replace

I have the following markup that shows a value from ng-model:

```html
<a ng-click="downloadDocument()">{{document.content.replace(/\d+\_/,"")}}</a>
```

Before each `document.content` I add a number and an underscore, something like `"12122141_document.txt"`. I want to replace this part by using the regex `/\d+\_/`.

This throws an error in AngularJS, although `{{ document.replace(" ","") }}` works.

Is the only way to solve this a directive or am I doing something wrong?

[Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/sh54XZwSIlYnmvY0eTIt/preview)

Comment: Use a $scope with ng-bind and try handle it in your backend. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope & https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Comment: It won't work with ng-bind.
Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/sh54XZwSIlYnmvY0eTIt/preview

Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 26-26 [\] in expression [document.content.replace(/\d+\_/,'')]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified your [Plunker-Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gYEuLmVMXao3fevHUPv0?p=preview) and it works pretty fine.

Hint: Don't use `$scope` namespaces like "document". Its reserved/used by the client.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
```

#### Controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.fileName = {
    content : function(){
      return '1233_test.txt'.replace(/\d+\_/,"");
    }
  }

  $scope.mpla = function () {
    console.log('clicked');
  }

});
```

#### View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p> 
  <a ng-click="mpla()" ng-bind="fileName.content()"></a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, the question was if I could do it by using curly brackets {{ }} on the .html file. Your solution is the next best thing so I added an ng-bind="getFilename()" and created this function to replace the string.

Comment: Using brackets is not the fine way in angular. Code inside brackets is parsed and executed not as $scope. Hope that helped ya out :). Cheers m8.